# Error message from query with more than on expression in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to write this without generating an error code?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findProd
    @SalesOrderID int,
    @SalesOrderOut int OUTPUT,
    @OrderDate datetime OUTPUT,
    @ShipDate int OUTPUT,
    @CityState varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @SalesOrderOut = @SalesOrderID

SET @OrderDate = (SELECT OrderDate FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader )

SET @CityState = (
    SELECT          City, StateProvinceCode AS 'State'
    FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
    ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
    ON              a.StateProvinceID=st.StateProvinceID            
    WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
    )
END
```

Error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't Set `@CityState` to more than 1 column from your select result. change these lines of codes:

```
SET @CityState = (
    SELECT          StateProvinceCode AS 'State'
    FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
    ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
    ON              a.StateProvinceID=st.StateProvinceID            
    WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
)
```

Comment: THANK YOU, Mohamad. I see now where @CityState was set in more than one column. I ran the modified code and it worked. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you on the blog? I would like to contact you. My contact deleye1@yandex.com

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
SET @OrderDate = (SELECT OrderDate FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader )
```

I believe you have multiple rows in SalesOrderHeader. So you might want to limit the rows or you might want to do add where clause so it selects just one orderDate.

Also you might want to check select here :

```
SET @CityState = (
SELECT          City -- i changed it to city and removed state from here
FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
ON              a.StateProvinceID=st.StateProvinceID            
WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
)
```

it returns one and only one city and you are selecting two fields instead select either city or state or concat both of them.

Comment: next line is problematic was well

Comment: Thanks Almas. I used where OrderDate=@OrderDate, but the same error message came up

Comment: @OrderDate in your proc is output parameter so i assume you are not passing it?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to have two Parameters, just so you can pass value to one and OUTPUT from other, You can use Single OUTPUT parameter to Pass values and OUTPUT value from it like below.

Also your second statement is just selecting Date value without any where clause which eventually returns a table(Multiple Rows) hence when you try to assign this table to a datetime variable you get error.

Lastly you are returing two columns and then trying to assign it to One variable in your last Select statement. Concatenate the values returned by two columns and assign it to your variable.

Best option is to always use TOP 1 when assiging values to variables like this, eliminates the chance of erroring out.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findProd
    @SalesOrderID int OUTPUT,
    @OrderDate    datetime OUTPUT,
    @ShipDate     int OUTPUT,
    @CityState    varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT TOP 1 @OrderDate = OrderDate 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID

SELECT TOP 1  @CityState =  ISNULL(City, '') + ISNULL(StateProvinceCode, '') 
FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
ON              a.StateProvinceID=st.StateProvinceID            
WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID

END
```